# How do I paste into the replace input area in vscode on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: vs code replace input area]

The actual task I was trying to perform was I had a ASCII based tree

```
+-root
  |
  +-branchA
  |
  +-branchB
    |
    +--leaf
```

and was trying to search and replace `+`, `-`, and `|` with [unicode box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) but I could find no way to paste those unicode characters into the replace box.

The obvious answer <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (MacOS) doesn't seem to work

Comment: I was able to paste some Japanese with ctrl v in ubuntu. Middle mouse pasted something else in the document instead. I even have paste in the context menu

Comment: if you click in replace as you would start to type, is there a context menu?

Comment: Have you seen this on all three of Mac /Linux and Windows? Or is this specific to one of your systems?

Comment: I found the issue. It was Mac only. I added Ctrl-V as a shortcut to paste. In that case both Cmd-V and Ctrl-V work in the editor but only Ctrl-V works in the replace area

Comment: I had similar issue few years ago. In my case, the problem was only happening when I opened the files using the console. Is this your case?

Comment: No, it happens always if you add a key for paste apparently. See answer. I solved it by adding both Ctrl-V and Cmd-V for paste in my keybindings.json

Answer (score 0):

The issue was it was Mac only. I added Ctrl-V as a binding to paste (since I use all 3 platforms and often press Ctrl-V by accident when on Mac). If I have the paste binding added then in that case both Cmd-V and Ctrl-V work in the editor but only Ctrl-V works in the replace area. If I remove the Ctrl-V binding suddenly Cmd-V starts working even though before removing it I see both bindings in the editor

I solved it by adding both Ctrl-V and Cmd-V for paste in my keybindings.json